# gh-pages - Jekyll fails to build - "did not find expected node content while parsing"

Tags: ruby, jekyll, github-pages

I'm trying to get a `gh-pages` site up and running. First time using Jekyll.

I have a super basic layout (`default.html`) in `/_layouts`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <section id="main">
        {{ content }}
      </section>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And a single content page (index.html)

```
---
layout: default
---
Hello World
```

My `_config.yml` file is simply

```
pygments: true
```

When running `jekyll --no-auto --server` I get the following error. No files are generated.

```
.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse':
(<unknown>): did not find expected node content while parsing a flow
node at line 3 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)
```

Anyone know what's wrong here?

Comment: The error is coming from [Psych](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych), Ruby’s Yaml parser, which suggests the error is in one of your Yaml files or in the [Yaml front matter](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/YAML-Front-Matter) of one of your pages. I can’t reproduce your error, but you should check your Yaml.

Comment: As far as I know the yaml and front matter posted is all that there is.

Answer (score 0):

Since line 3 is `<head>`, it is possible that some basic metadata is missing, like `<title>`.
All template I see have a title (zinga, [Symplicity](https://github.com/Symplicity/Symplicity-GH-Pages/blob/master/_layouts/default.html), ... either fixed or generated), and the most basic template has one too (see "[Hello World, I'm Jekyll](http://destroytoday.com/blog/hello-world-im-jekyll/)")

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello world!</h1>
    <p>This is my first Jekyll website.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think line 3 refers to a yaml file but I'll take a look at that tutorial when I get home. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should check that what it's parsing is YAML at all.

The way I'm checking this in by putting some debug commands in the gem directly and re-running.

Change the `psych.rb` which for me is at `/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb`. Look for the `def self.load` and change it from

```
def self.load yaml, filename = nil
  result = parse(yaml, filename)
  result ? result.to_ruby : result
end
```

to

```
def self.load yaml, filename = nil
  puts "****************#{filename}"
  result = parse(yaml, filename)
  result ? result.to_ruby : result
end
```

and look for the output in your terminal when you re-run the command.

I am currently dealing with deploying a rails app with capistrano (no jekyll at all). In my case, the output was blank, which is obviously not a filename. So now I'm investigating further up the chain. I hope that gets you started.